# How do I create a self-closing link inside a tipsy tooltip without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tipsy

I'm using Tipsy to display some content; inside this content I have a link (a big X) that is intended to close the tooltip. However, when clicked, it simply jumps to the top of the page and fails to close the tooltip, even though I have it set to return false. My code looks like this:

```
$(".favs").tipsy({
    fade: true,
    gravity: 'n',
    trigger: "manual",
    html: true,
    offset: 5,
    opacity: '0.9',
    delayIn: 0,
    delayOut: 0,
    title:
      function() {
        return $("#favs_1").html();
      }
    });

  $(".favs").click(function(){
    $(this).tipsy("show");
    return false;
  });

  $(".closetip").click(function(){
    $(".tipsy").remove();
    return false;
  });
```

Applied to this HTML:

```
<div style="height: 1800px;">
    <br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="#" class="favs">Favorite Movies</a>
</div>

<div id="favs_1" style="display: none;">
  <a href="#" class="closetip" style="float: right;">X</a>

  Tooltip content
</div>
```

Relevant fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gZkJJ/

I solved half the problem by having any click result in a tooltip closure. I tried to exempt clicks in certain divs from this with event.stopPropagation(); -- that led to the tooltip being closed, but a) the divs in question were not exempt and b) the X still jumped to the top of the page. Same HTML as above, but with this slightly different JavaScript:

```
$(".favs").tipsy({
    fade: true,
    gravity: 'n',
    trigger: "manual",
    html: true,
    offset: 5,
    opacity: '0.9',
    delayIn: 0,
    delayOut: 0,
    title:
      function() {
        return $("#favs_1").html();
      }
    });

  $(".favs").click(function(){
    $(this).tipsy("show");
    return false;
  });

  $("html, .closetip").click(function() {
    $(".tipsy").remove();
  });

  $(".tipsy, .tipsy-n, .tipsy-inner, .favs").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Relevant fiddle for this variation: http://jsfiddle.net/u62eH/

I included the excessive height and spacing so that you can verify the link is either reloading the frame or forcing a scroll to the top, which you can do by scrolling down slightly before hitting the X.

Any help would be much appreciated. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event handler for clicking on either the `html` element or the `.closetip` element, call `e.preventDefault()` if it was the anchor:

```
$("html, .closetip").click(function(e) {
    if(e.target.nodeName === 'A')
        e.preventDefault();
    $(".tipsy").remove();
});
```

Comment: That definitely fixes the second part! Many thanks. Bad oversight on my part. Can this be easily extended or tweaked to address the first, IE: to only close the tooltip if the click is either a) from the link or b) outside the tooltip? I'm going to have other links inside the tooltip that still need to function without it closing.

Comment: Yeah, I've been playing with this some more and it seems like it stops any links from inside the tooltip from working. Is there a way to only call preventDefault() for that one?

Comment: Alright, I ended up going with this: if (e.target.nodeName === 'A' && e.target.className == "whatever"). It still closes the tooltip when another link is clicked, but the other links work, so that's close enough. :)